# How can I improve the performance of converting an SVG to PDF using Apache Batik?

Tags: pdf, svg, apache-fop, batik

I am using Apache Batik version 1.9 to convert from SVG to PDF. I am getting the desired result, but it is consuming a lot of time to generate the PDF output. Below is the code. I am not sure how to improve its performance. Is there a way I can achieve better performance?

```
// svgBytes is the input
ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Transcoder transcoder = new PDFTranscoder();

InputStream svgInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(svgBytes);

// Parse SVG
SAXSVGDocumentFactory f = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName());
Document svgDoc = f.createDocument(null, svgInputStream);
SVGDocument svgDocument = (SVGDocument) svgDoc;
SVGElement root = svgDocument.getRootElement();
Float svgWidth = Float.parseFloat(null == root.getAttribute("width") ? SVG_DEFAULT_WIDTH : root.getAttribute("width"));
Float svgHeight = Float.parseFloat(null == root.getAttribute("height") ? SVG_DEFAULT_HEIGHT : root.getAttribute("height"));

// Convert SVG to PDF using batik
float scalePercentage = 1f;
transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PDFTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, new Float(svgWidth * scalePercentage));
transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PDFTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, new Float(svgHeight * scalePercentage));
transcoder.transcode(new TranscoderInput(new ByteArrayInputStream(svgBytes)), new TranscoderOutput(pdfOutputStream));

pdfOutputStream.flush();
pdfOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: Simplify the SVG perhaps.

Comment: @Nithin Can you provide same svg. performace is based on svg content.

Comment: @RavipatiPraveen Thanks for the update. I am using d3 version 3 to generate svg's. I could see that even for simple svg's to convert to pdf , the time consumption was more. Anyway, i will share the svg.

Comment: @RobertLongson Even for Simple SVG's the result is same